# How to run the UI script in Headless mode for edge browser

Tags: testing, karate

I have an scenario where I want to trigger the UI script in Microsoft Edge with headless mode. How to achieve this?

```
* configure driver = { type: 'msedgedriver', webDriverSession: { capabilities: { browserName: 'edge' } }, executable: '#(executable)' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing the `headless` flag inside the capabilities? Something like this

```
* configure driver = { type: 'msedgedriver', webDriverSession: { capabilities: { browserName: 'edge', headless: true } }, executable: '#(executable)'}
```

Taken from the documentation mentioned [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#driver-configuration).

Comment: Still it's not working. I have used 
* configure driver = { type: 'msedgedriver', webDriverSession: { capabilities: { browserName: 'edge', headless: true } }, executable: '#(executable)' }

Comment: Do you see any error or it directly opens the browser?

Comment: It directly opens the browser. No Error is occurring.

Comment: @peter/demouser123 kindly help me to resolve this.